# How to fetch and set SEO tags data like title and meta desc in Nextjs 13?

Tags: next.js, seo

I am getting SEO contet through an API, but the API takes a little bit of time to load, by the time it is not showiing the title, also when i share the link somewhere, the title is not showing, I tried fetching the SEO content from getServerSideProps, but still it takes a bit of time, I dont want to show "Loading..." or something while it loads, rather I would fetch the SEO content before the page loads, is it possible somehow?

Below is the code I have written as of now.

```
const Index = ({ seoTags }) => {
    <Head>
        <title>{seoTags[0]?.meta_title}</title>
        <meta name="robots" content={seoTags[0]?.meta_robots} />
        <meta name="description" content={seoTags[0]?.meta_description} />
        <meta name="title" content={seoTags[0]?.meta_title} />
    </Head>
    ...
}
export default Index;
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  try {
    var response = await fetch(
      `https://test.com/rest/V1/homepage-titles`
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  let seoTags = [];

  if (response) {
    seoTags = await response.json();
  }

  return {
    props: {
      seoTags: seoTags,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `<meta name="title">`  You are already using the `<title>` tag, so deleted the meta tag with the title.

Comment: You should read the [next.js documentation for server side rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/server-side-rendering).